# How can I run/debug my android app on my device via USB from my mac?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following along with the tutorial provided by the Android Developers official site and using the help files in Android Studio, but I'm finding out of date screenshots and feeling very confused and a little frustrated.

I have a Pixel 2 connected via usb.
I've enabled developer mode on the device.
I've got it not sleeping when connected via USB.
I've enabled USB debugging in the Developer Options on the phone.

...I just need to figure out how to get my Mac to see it via Android Studio.

The tutorial alludes to a configuration screen that I don't see in studio. I see something similar but the device drop down is disabled.

[image: disabled device menu]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot so that we can see?

Comment: If I could provide a screenshot, I'd know what I was looking for. But here is a link to the tutorial that seems outdated 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run#run-configuration

Comment: is your app building when you click on the sync button ?

Comment: Sorry, what does the sync button look like?

Comment: Form right 5th icon(Elephant with down arrow)

Comment: I get spinners in the build window
And a message to download something.. but I can't copy the url. I would assume it's going to download that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200972/discussion-between-pixelfairy-and-swayangjit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hit the sync button,
- Wait for downloads(don't stop the hidden downloads)
- Restart if necessary, wait for the first invocation to complete work.
- Then  enjoy your first app.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

answer: hit the sync button (elephant/mouse looking icon with a diagonal arrow), wait for downloads, don't stop the hidden downloads, then restart if necessary, wait for first invocation to complete, ...then it will (hopefully) work.